# Waterfall tooltip on chrome developer tools does not show correctly

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

This is reproducible both to Chrome  96.0.4664.45 and Edge  96.0.1054.62..,
I see something like this:
[image: 1],

although I expected something like this [image: 2]

Comment: I see the same on Chrome 97.0.4692.71